# WSO2 EI 6.1.1 Data Mapper mediator to transform one json format to another json format

Tags: datamapper, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I want to use WSO2 EI's Data Mapper Mediator to transform a json response coming out of one endpoint to another json format as required. Sample JSON response from my endpoint is -

```
{
    "CUSTOMER360": {       
            "CUSTOMER_ID": "24339"

    }
}
```

I want this to convert to the following format:

```
{
    "customer360": {
        "customer": {
            "id": "24339"
        }
    }
}
```

I have created one ESB project and given a simple workflow to look at how to use Data Mapper mediator. My API code goes like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/customerDataAPI" name="CustomerDataMapperAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST GET">
        <inSequence>
            <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/CustomerDataConfig.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/CustomerDataConfig_inputSchema.json" inputType="JSON" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/CustomerDataConfig_outputSchema.json" outputType="JSON"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

I have taken care of loading input and output json schemas into Data Mapper mediator and giving correct mapping. Also, mentioned input and output type to be JSON in properties view of Data Mapper and included mapping related files in the CAR file. When I invoke my API - I get this error:

```
ERROR - SequenceMediator Runtime error occurred whi
le mediating the message
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.JSONInputRea
der.readFromInputStream(JSONInputReader.java:76)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.JSONInputRea
der.read(JSONInputReader.java:59)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.InputBuilder.buildIn
putModel(InputBuilder.java:59)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.core.mapper.MappingHandler
.doMap(MappingHandler.java:88)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.transform(Data
MapperMediator.java:309)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.mediate(DataMa
pperMediator.java:259)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
tMediator.java:89)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
tMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMe
diator.java:158)
```

Can someone please help me where I might have gone wrong. Also, please tell me how I can input to the Data Mapper mediator, the json response that comes from an endpoint.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The exception occurred because of a json file you're trying to access which is not available. So can you please check if these two files are actually available in the governance registry? `CustomerDataConfig_inputSchema.json` and `CustomerDataConfig_outputSchema.json`